# Why there is no transition from `green` to `blue`?

Tags: reactjs

What I learned is `useLayoutEffect` called before **browser paints** and `useEffect` called after **paint**. so, why there is no transition from **green** to **blue**?

```
function App() {
  const [color, setColor] = useState('red');
  
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    setColor('green');
  }, [])
  
  useEffect(() => {
    setColor('blue');
  }, [])
  
  return (
    <h1
      style={{
        color,
        transition: 'color 300ms ease-in-out'
      }}
    >
      Hello World
    </h1>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While it is true *when* each hook fires, that fact is that they are still occurring within the same render cycle and both enqueue state updates. The `useLayoutEffect` hook fires earlier in order to allow you to take DOM measurements and compute layout.

```
useLayoutEffect(() => {
  setColor('green');
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  setColor('blue');
}, []);
```

When multiple state updates are enqueued within the same render cycle each subsequent update overwrites the computed state of the previous update. In other words, the last update to state from the previous render cycle is the one used for the next render cycle.

From a component state perspective, the component sees state update from 'red' to 'blue'.